# VUE2 - CSS inclusion and order

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I try include and order CSS stylesheets in my Vue2 application.

The problem is, that the application don't follow the order in App.vue

I add in the end of App.vue following code:

```
<style>
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '/static/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
@import '../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
@import '/static/css/style.css';
</style>
```

When I run application, style.css is not at the end.
Is there any way to make the order correct? Have style.css at end?

Comment: This is a webpack (assuming you are using the one of the vue-cli templates) issue, not anything to do with vue.js. So you may have better luck finding the answer if you tag it with webpack or include webpack in your search.

Comment: Seems like bug in webpack: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/200 Need find the temporary solution. Maybe change @import to require